# How to fix USB keyboard and mouse issues in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb

After restoring from Windows 8 upgrade, I have noticed that Windows Device Manager could not initialize previously working devices. I have tried to reinstall USB controllers and things went from bad to worst. Now keyboard and mouse are not recognized, so I'm left with a pretty useless system.

- I have tried to use other USB mouse that working with my laptop, but nothing has changed.
- Tried to connect wired mouse via PS2 adapter, no luck system is not recognizing it.
- Launched Ubuntu from USB stick, all working fine, (Currently using it)
- Tried to insert Windows 7 installation disk, repair option does not fix anything, but I'm able to launch command prompt.

What's interesting that for few minutes before login screen mouse is working so I have just enough time to launch assistance and call virtual keyboard, after that it's unresponsive again.

I'm running out of options and would like to know is anything else could be done with current options, apart from buying new appliance or completely reinstalling windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

This looks for me like a driver issue. You could try to download drivers for your motherboard and burning it to a disc while being on Ubuntu, then installing them on Windows.

If it does not help, then it might be an overflow in memory on your computer. In that case, back up all important data (images, videos or/and others), and try to re-install Windows, if you have possibility to do so.